# Regexp_Substr for Semicolon in query for ORACLE DB

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g

I have got the REGEXP_SUBSTR to split the semi-colon but the issue is that if there is no data between two semi-colon there the next data is shifted one column before.

Here is the below example.

Data in Oracle DB column

```
ColumnXYZ
A;;B
```

Now the my query is

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(COLUMNXYZ, '[^;]+', 1, 1) as COL1,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(COLUMNXYZ, '[^;]+', 1, 2) as COL2,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(COLUMNXYZ, '[^;]+', 1, 3) as COL3,
FROM TABLE T
```

After execution is show below data

```
COL1  COL2  COl3
A      B    null
```

but the I need the output in below format as between two semi-colon there is no value.

```
COL1   COL2  COL3  
A      null  B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 'A;B;C' AS col FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'A;B;' AS col FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT ';B;C' AS col FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'A;;C' AS col FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'A;;' AS col FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT ';B;' AS col FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT ';;C' AS col FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT ';;' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT col
    , REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, '([^;]*)(;|$)', 1, 1, '', 1) AS col1
    , REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, '([^;]*)(;|$)', 1, 2, '', 1) AS col2
    , REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, '([^;]*)(;|$)', 1, 3, '', 1) AS col3
FROM cte
```

The pattern `([^;]*)(;|$)` matches zero or more non-semicolons followed by semicolon or end of string. Grouping is used to convert each match into two sub matches e.g. `A;` becomes `A` and `;`.

Comment: It is working fine. Thanks @Salman A. Now I have to add the  ;[^;]*  in all the next rows to fetch the data. It will make the query a bit large, but at-least it will work. Do You have any other code to avoid this as I have 20 columns to fetch

Comment: @Sanju I have simplified it.

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT   ROWNUM AS num_row,
           REGEXP_SUBSTR(REPLACE(REPLACE('A;;B', ';;', '; ;'),';;','; ;'), '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL) AS par_value
  FROM     dual
  CONNECT  BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(REPLACE(REPLACE('A;;B', ';;', '; ;'),';;','; ;'), '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
```

Or if You need null column:

```
SELECT  num_row,
        CASE
          WHEN par_value = '#$N#$' THEN NULL
          ELSE par_value
        END as par_value
FROM    (
          SELECT   ROWNUM AS num_row,
                   REGEXP_SUBSTR(REPLACE(REPLACE('A;;B', ';;', ';#$N#$;'),';;','; ;'), '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL) AS par_value
          FROM     dual
          CONNECT  BY
                   REGEXP_SUBSTR(REPLACE(REPLACE('A;;B', ';;', ';#$N#$;'),';;','; ;'), '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
        )
```

## $N#$ is example value for null

Comment: q4za4 :- Thanks for sharing your response. As I executed the query, getting the value in **Column wise** . I need the values in **Row wise**. I need to execute the same in web application and then application will created PDF or XLS as per user request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace` with `'; ;'` argument, and then `trim`

```
with t1 as
(select replace('A;;B',';;','; ;') as str from dual 
),
     t2(col1,col2,col3) as
(
 select regexp_substr(str, '[^;]+', 1, 1),
        trim(regexp_substr(str, '[^;]+', 1, 2)),
        regexp_substr(str, '[^;]+', 1, 3) 
   from t1
)   
select * from t2;

  COL1  COL2  COL3
  ----  ----  ----
  A     null  B
```

**Edit** *depending on your comment :*

If you want row-wise result, consider the following query :

```
with t1 as
 (select replace('A;;B',';;','; ;') as str from dual)
   select trim(regexp_substr(str, '[^;]+', 1, level))
       as "Result String"
     from t1
    cross join dual
  connect by level <= length(regexp_replace(str, ';',''));

Result String
-------------
A

B
```